# I am looping over a dataframe pypandas. I want to count current value in a specific column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am newbie in python and really need your help!

I am looping over a DF and trying to eliminate the rows based on a specific criteria.

Criteria in pseudo: If `count(DF[[i],[3]].values,'b')>1` then `DF.drop([i],axis=0)`

I tried reading a lot of documentation but failed.

```py
for i in range(0,A):

    if pd.isnull(DF.iloc[[i],[0]].values) or (DF.iloc[[i],[3]].values!='Rights' and DF.iloc[[i],[3]].values!='Div'):
        AV=AV.drop([i],axis=0)
    elif DF.iloc[[i],[2]].count(axis='C')>1:
        pass
    else:
        AV=AV.drop([i],axis=0)
```

Can you please help me?

here is a sample of my dataframe
Ideally, i would have only rows 1,3,5 and 7.

[DF sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whw5d.png)

Thanks,
Mash

Comment: post a few rows of your dataframe to get an idea of what you are trying to do

Comment: I added a sample of my DF and what results I expect.
Thanks abhilb

Comment: In your question you have stated that you need rows 1,3,5 and 7. Why not row 2 too? Change Type==Rights

Comment: Because it is not duplicated. I need duplicates only. That is why, i want to know how to count in a single value in a particular column in a data frame